# If..else works as OR, does it true?

Tags: python, if-statement

Does `if..elif` statements works exactly as one OR statement?

For example does below `if..elif`:

```
if X == "a": 
    Y = 1 
elif Z == "b" and V = "c": 
    Y = 1
```

Works as

```
if X == "a" or (Z == "b" and V == "c"):  
    Y = 1
```

Comment: it does because you have for both conditions the same statement(Y=1). It wouldn't work as OR statement when Y = 1 for the first condition(x=="a") and Y = 2 for the second where with the OR statement you wouldn't be able to specify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in your specific case the functionality is the same. You would use an `if`/`elif` statement if you were going to do two *different* things based upon the condition which executes to `True`. For example,

```
if a == 'a':
    y = 1
elif z == 'b' and v == 'c':
    y = 2
```

However, since in both cases you are doing `Y = 1`, then

```
if x == 'a' or (z == 'b' and v == 'c'):
    y = 1
```

works just fine and even is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The effect in your code is the same. But **it doesn't work the same way**. The `or` statement looks at the two statements and will return `True` if at least one of the statements are true. On the other hand, the `if`...`elif` statement would just go into one of the conditions. Either only into the `if` statement, or only into the `elif` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I wasn't clear enough on my question - I meant output mainly. You are certainly right.

Comment: output-wise, it is the same.